# Behavior of async package

Tags: haskell, asynchronous

What would the following code using the `async` package do:

```
action <- async $ mapM_ someFunc someList
wait action
```

Will this merely spawn a single thread in which `mapM_` occurs? (Implying that this has no benefit over just `mapM_ someFunc someList`)

Or will it perform the `mapM_` action asynchronously (or is `mapConcurrently` the only way to get such behavior)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will this merely spawn a single thread in which mapM_ occurs?

Yes, it will fork a thread and immediately block waiting for the mapM_ to finish and return a `()` (or to throw an exception).

The `async` package is very simple; you might like to look at the source to see how it all works together and learn more about the underlying haskell concurrency primitives.